# How to handle user registration with multiple pages and entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

So I am at point in my project where I need to implement a user registration system for an MVC 3 application with Entity Framework.

I have the following entities that are/need to be filled as part of registrations:

- User
- Person
- Role
- Business

The old application (we'll call it v1)  handled the sign up process with a class to contain all the data, and then after each step in registration, saved the class to session

I'm just getting my feet wet with MVC3/EF4.1.  My initial scouring for information had me looking at a repository, and unit of work pattern to handle this.  However, I am seeing a few sources that say repository patterns are not really needed with MVC3/Ef4.1.

so my question is this.  do i create user registration like it was in v1, and that class being saved to session is now technically a repository, or is there a better way to harness MVC3/EF4.1 to handle registering a new user with a flow that spans mulitple pages/views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our MVC3 registration spans multiple page views (progressive disclosure) with similar entities (User / Person / Roles / Affiliation with Establishments). I'm not sure whether you have a full grasp on the Repository or UnitOfWork patterns though. These are persistence-related patterns, and don't really have anything to do with session, which is an HTTP state management mechanism.

I suggest you write to the database at the end of each page view (when user submits form), rather than accumulating all of the data in session. If you need to pass info from one view to another in the chain, you can use the controller's TempData dictionary to store entity keys (TempData actually uses Session in the background).

There is a possibility that you can end up with incomplete information in the database with this approach, if a user does not complete all of the registration steps. However, it allows you to let them continue the registration process without having to re-enter information too. Whereas, if you were using session, and your user accidentally closed their browser window, all of that session data would be lost, and the user would have to start over.

What we do is collect the user & password first. The flow goes like this:

1. User enters email address (form 1)
2. If eligible, confirmation email is sent to address
3. User confirms email address using emailed secret (form 2)
4. User creates password (form 3)
5. User enters Person info (form 4)
6. User enters Business info (form 5)

If a user has only completed a subset of these steps, we can use the database info to determine which step is next in the registration process, and funnel them into that view until the registration process is complete.

Comment: interesting.  I think we were trying to avoid the writing to the database with each step to prevent a partial or abandoned registration occurrence.  I just had the idea of creating a large model to pass from one page to the next, and each page then fills in the properties related to that step in registration.

Comment: You would still end up having to save that model to keep it between page loads (assume you are still thinking session). If you are avoiding writing to the db to prevent partial or abandoned registrations, why? If you can justify this with good reasons, you can create separate entities in your db for storing data during each step. Then, when the process is complete, move the data to the "real" entities. This way, you don't end up with session hogging the memory on your server.

Comment: ran out of character space. see answer

Comment: i really can't come up with a great reason to not save to the database.

Answer (score 1):

ran out of characters in comment response.  can i do something like this?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UserInfo(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserInfo(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    return View("BusinessInfo",model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BusinessInfo(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BusinessInfo(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    return View("LicenseAgreement",model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LicenseAgreement(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Webforms flashback! How would you implement validation on your RegistrationViewModel? If you submit it in the UserInfo action, the invalid fields would cause ModelState.IsValid to be false. Also, how would you pass the RegistrationViewModel data to the BusinessInfo HttpGet action method?

Comment: you raise very good points.  so the recommended implementation would be to create a large entity and have view models that submit/update to that entity?

Comment: That is one approach, though I'm not sure it is the simplest. Like I mentioned, for us, we don't duplicate entity data to make sure we get everything-or-nothing. We considered it, but couldn't find a good reason to justify waiting until the registration was complete before saving to the db. We create an email entry, then a user/password entry, then a person entry, then an affiliation entry. Using the data in the db, we can determine which step is the next in the process, and which data is stale / can safely be purged.